# Rails WebMock error on the second request try ::NetConnectNotAllowedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webmock

I want to mock custom devise strategies to authenticate user in my feature specs. To stub request to 3th party app I'm using WebMock with the implementation below:

`spec/utility/stub_methods.rb`

```
  def stub_aware_auth(creds, returns_token, _valid)
    stub_request(:post, "http://example.com/oauth/token").
        with(body: {"grant_type" => "password", "password" => creds.password, "username" => creds.email},
             headers: {'Accept' => '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}).
        to_return(status: 200, body: {'access_token' => returns_token, 'token_type' => 'bearer', 'expires_in' => 1200}.to_json, headers: {})
  end
```

Which is called in the spec by:

```
context 'AWARxE authenticated user' do
  before do
    stub_aware_auth(creds, return_token, valid)  
  end

  let(:creds) do
    OpenStruct.new(email: 'physiciansreallyshouldonlyautoauth@example.com', password: "Ican'tb3li3v3itsn0tbutt3r")
  end
  let(:return_token) { SecureRandom.hex(32) }
  let(:valid) { true }
  # other logic (...)
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Which works quite surprisingly wired because if in one test example it has to use `stub_aware_auth` twice, the first request returns the defined result but the second throws an error:

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST http://example.com/oauth/token with body 'grant_type=password&password=Ican%27tb3li3v3itsn0tbutt3r&username=PHYSICIANSREALLYSHOULDONLYAUTOAUTH%40EXAMPLE.COM' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.12.1'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:post, "http://example.com/oauth/token").
  with(body: {"grant_type"=>"password", "password"=>"Ican'tb3li3v3itsn0tbutt3r", "username"=>"PHYSICIANSREALLYSHOULDONLYAUTOAUTH@EXAMPLE.COM"},
       headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.12.1'}).
  to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})

registered request stubs:

stub_request(:get, "http://example.com/api/v1/user").
  with(headers: {'Authorization'=>'Bearer dc2dcf4c5b47ffcfea28c26490ed2a0e2580f152dfb18dbfc97670028d24ecaa'})
stub_request(:post, "http://example.com/oauth/token").
  with(body: {"grant_type"=>"password", "password"=>"Ican'tb3li3v3itsn0tbutt3r", "username"=>"physiciansreallyshouldonlyautoauth@example.com"},
       headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Which is surprised because `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)` is defined in spec_helper.

[EDIT]

Full failed example if it helps:

`spec/features/login_strategies_spec.rb`

```
  context 'AWARxE authenticated user' do
    before do
      stub_aware_auth(creds, return_token, valid)
    end

    let(:return_token) { SecureRandom.hex(32) }
    let(:valid) { true }
    context 'physician' do
      let(:creds) do
        OpenStruct.new(email: 'physiciansreallyshouldonlyautoauth@example.com', password: "Ican'tb3li3v3itsn0tbutt3r")
      end
      let(:user) { build(:physician) }

      before do
        stub_aware_user_info(user, 'Physician (MD, DO)', return_token, valid, 1)
      end
      
      # some other it block (...)

      context 'case insensitive' do
        let(:valid) { true }
        let(:uppercase_email_creds) {
          OpenStruct.new(email: creds.email.upcase, password: creds.password)
        }

        scenario 'logging in with upper case email' do
          expect { subject }.to change(Login, :count)
          logout
          expect {
            login(uppercase_email_creds)
          }.to_not change(Login, :count)
          expect(page).to have_current_path(name_search_registrants_url, url: true)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Could you add the example that fails? As in, the exact way you are calling `stub_aware_auth` and then the test itself?

Comment: @rewritten I don't know if this will help you but here you go.

Comment: Indeed, check the answer now. Either you are not stubbing what you would stub (the call with uppercase email) oor your app is not downcasing correctly (so the test should fail indeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stub you are creating is still on the original `creds` with the lowercase email. There is no possibility for webmock to mock the call unless you actually call something like

```rb
      stub_aware_auth(uppercase_email_creds, return_token, valid)
```

If you actualy expect the app to call out with lowercase email in body, then the test fails because it should fail, it is calling out with the email in uppercase:

```
You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:post, "http://example.com/oauth/token").
  with(body: {..., "username"=>"PHYSICIANSREALLYSHOULDONLYAUTOAUTH@EXAMPLE.COM"},
       ...).
  to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})
```